# Insert new object with realtion to new objects with identity column

Tags: entity-framework-4

Customer class:

```
class Customer 
{ 
  int id; 
  int phone;
  int fax;
  PhoneNumber phone1;
  PhoneNumber fax1;
}

Class PhoneNumber
{
int id;
int prefixid;
string number;
}
```

The PhoneNumber was auto-Generated by EF4, I've change the auto-generated names to phone1 and fax1

Both phonenumber id and customer id are identity columns in the DB.

Now I want to create a new Customer:

```
       var newCustomer = Customer.CreateCustomer(0, CompanyID);
        PhoneNumber fax = new PhoneNumber();
        PhoneNumber phone = new PhoneNumber();

        fax.Customers.Add(newCustomer);
        phone.Customers.Add(newCustomer);

        context.Customers.AddObject(newCustomer);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

But now I get:

> System.Data.UpdateException: {"Cannot
>   insert explicit value for identity
>   column in table 'PhoneNumber' when
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}

Why isn't EF4 deal with the identity column of the related table as it should deal with a new entity ? How can I make this work ?

(EF4 Should've  create 2 entiries in Phones table, get their identity and add it to the customer row of the new customer - at least that what I want to do)

I know I Can create 2 Phone records, and than create the customer one, but

a. I want it to be done in one act.

b. if cusotmer creation fails - I don't want empty records on the phones table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well these two things contradict each other:

> Both phonenumber id and customer id are identity columns in the DB.

But then the error:

> System.Data.UpdateException: {"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'PhoneNumber' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}

It may seem like this error is saying a duplicate identity is being set, but it's not - it's saying your trying to explicitly set the identity field.

What that is saying is that the ID column in PhoneNumber is **not an identity field**. Or at least EF does not think it is.

So i have four questions:

1) Have you confirmed the field is set to IDENTITY in the EDMX? Maybe something has overriden it?

2) What does the `CreateCustomer` method do? Does it just new up a Customer and set some properties? It should not touch the identity fields.

3) Have you setup the navigational properties/cardinalities properly on the EDMX? E.g 1 Customer .. 1-* Phone Numbers.

4) Try adding the Phone number to the Customer, not the other way around. It makes sense to add the "many" to the "one" - e.g Customer is the aggregate here:

```
var newCustomer = Customer.CreateCustomer(0, CompanyID);
newCustomer.phone1 = new PhoneNumber();
newCustomer.fax1 = new PhoneNumber();
context.Customers.AddObject(newCustomer);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I'd also suggest redesigning your model.

It's silly to have Customer with 1 Fax and 1 Phone Number, each with a property on there. It should be a Customer have many "PhoneNumber" entities.

You could use TPH on the PhoneNumber entity to discriminate between Fax and other types, and the above code would make much more sense:

```
var newCustomer = Customer.CreateCustomer(0, CompanyID);
newCustomer.Phones.Add(new FaxNumber());
newCustomer.Phones.Add(new MobileNumber());
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. 1. EDMX was auto-generated. the phonenumber id is identity in DB, and it is not on EDMX - I am trying to fix it now. 2. this method was auto-generated by VS2010. 3. each customer has actually 4 phone numbers. it has 4 navigation properties, which I only changed their names. 4. I did that also - got the same error. your design is better, but I want each customer to have exactly 4 phone numbers, 1 of them is fax and 1 is cell - so I made it a fixed relation (1:4) and not 1:N. I'm changing edmx manually and trying again (identity)

Comment: I've changed PhoneNumber ID to be identity in EDMX, tried both ways (also tried to do  newCustomer.CellNumber = new PhoneNumber(); ) and the same error occurs.

Comment: OK. Changed the Phone ID to be identity in the XML file (found another location that wasn't changed by the model browser)  - and it worked as expected !! thanks again.